# Голосовой набор

Tags: android, java

Компилятор ругается на **VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE**, когда я использую функции для голосового набора.

```
Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE cannot be resolved to a variable    Newnote.java
```

Может что-то в манифесте нужно объявить?

Comment: Какое api? Поставь выше

Comment: У меня 8..

Comment: поставь 10+